# c# excel interop charts

Tags: c#, excel, charts, interop

I have a question: how to remove the displaying of zeros and percents?
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLmEt.png)

And second question: if I have only zeros then the diagram is empty. Is there any method to fill the chart with the inscription? For example, "no data".

[chart2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HkXN.png)

```
#region 123




        Excel.ChartObjects xlChart1 = (Excel.ChartObjects)WorkSheet_2.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myxlChart1 = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChart1.Add(600, 1110, 450, 450);
        Excel.Chart chartpage1 = myxlChart1.Chart;
        Excel.SeriesCollection col = chartpage1.SeriesCollection();
        chartpage1.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlPie;

        chartpage1.ChartArea.Border.Color = Color.FromArgb(30, 82, 255).ToArgb();

        Excel.SeriesCollection chartpage1seriesCollection = chartpage1.SeriesCollection();
        SeriesCollection seriesCollection3ddef = (SeriesCollection)chartpage1.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing);
        Series series1= seriesCollection3ddef.NewSeries();




        series1.XValues = WorkSheet_2.get_Range("BF3", "BM3");
        series1.Values = WorkSheet_2.get_Range("BF15", "BM15");

        Excel.Axis myaxis = chartpage1.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary) as Excel.Axis;



        series1.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowLabel, false, Type.Missing, false, false, false, true, Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowPercent, false, "\n");
        series1.DataLabels().Font.Name = "Arial";
        series1.DataLabels().Font.Size = 12;
        series1.DataLabels().Orientation = 0;





        chartpage1.HasLegend = true;
        chartpage1.Legend.Border.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.DarkRed);
        chartpage1.Legend.Position = XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionCorner;
        chartpage1.Legend.Font.Name = "Arial";
        chartpage1.Legend.Font.Size = 10;
     ;

        chartpage1.HasTitle = true;
        chartpage1.ChartTitle.Text = "MyChart, \n N, pcs";
        chartpage1.ChartTitle.Position = XlChartElementPosition.xlChartElementPositionAutomatic;
        chartpage1.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14;
        chartpage1.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Arial";
        chartpage1.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = true;


        x3l.PlotArea(chartpage1, ChartHeight * 0.30, ChartWidth * 0.06, ChartHeight * 0.8, ChartWidth * 0.8);


        #endregion
```

Thanks!

Comment: @JohnB I need a help and not the rules of the title design.
The essence of the problem is stated. I'm waiting for constructive answers.

Comment: and we're waiting or a constructive question...with for example what you have tried so far, you code...